# JPA One-to-many relationship with composite id in both father and child

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, one-to-many

The tables:

```
FATHER_TABLE (PK CONF_ID, CONF_TYPE)
CONF_ID (NUMBER(2)),
CONF_TYPE(VARCHAR2(10),
... some other ininfluent columns

CHILD TABLE (PK CONF_ID, CONF_TYPE, CONF_DETAIL)
CONF_ID (NUMBER(2)),
CONF_TYPE(VARCHAR2(10),
CONF_DETAIL(NUMBER(2)),
... some other ininfluent columns
```

The Father table entity is defined as:

```
public class FatherId implements Serializable {   
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Long confId;
    private String confType;

    //equals and hashcode
}


@Entity
@IdClass(FatherId.class)
@Table(name = "FATHER_TABLE")
public class Father {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "CONF_ID")
    private Long confId;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "CONF_TYPE")
    private String confType;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="father", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Child> = new HashSet<Child>
}
```

How can I refer to the `FatherId` in my hypothetical `ChildId` IdClass or directly in a `Child` entity class?

Comment: You implement the `FatherId` class but you're not using it later on? Have you tried kind of this https://stackoverflow.com/a/1009437/1199132 ?

Comment: I need to persist father with its child collection. Problem is I don't know how to map father as child id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a "derived identity", and you can map `Child` like this:

```
public class ChildId implements Serializable {
    private Long confDetail; // matches the name of the attribute
    private FatherId father;  // matches name of attribute and type of Father PK
    ...
}


@Entity
@IdClass(ChildId.class)
@Table(name = "CHILD_TABLE")
public class Father {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "CONF_DETAIL")
    private Long confDetail;

    @Id
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name="CONF_ID", referencedColumnName="CONF_ID"),
        @JoinColumn(name="CONF_TYPE", referencedColumnName="CONF_TYPE")
    })
    @ManyToOne
    Father father;
}
```

Derived identities are discussed (with examples) in the JPA 2.1 spec in section 2.4.1.

Comment: Working perfectly (I've just had to update my `persistence.xml` from 2.0 to 2.1), thanks for the answer.